# Go runtime:panic before malloc heap initialized

Tags: go

I'm using windows 7 32 bit enterprise when i type godoc on cmd it gives me following exception:

runtime: panic before malloc heap initialized 
fatal error: runtime: cannot reverve arena virtual address space

GO version : go1.2rc5.windows-386.msi 
OS : Windows 7 enterprise 32 bit

Comment: Assuming your question is "What should I do to get godoc running?": Get more RAM.

Comment: Not only for godoc it's just whenever i try compile it gives me the error

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have enough free (physical) RAM, no virtual address space restrictions and 
try restarting the program with administrator privileges (there are [reports of UAC](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2290) messing around). If that does not help, [report an issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/).

#### What the error means

> fatal error: runtime: cannot reverve arena virtual address space

Go reserves a memory region in *virtual address space*.
This memory region is used for Gos internal memory allocations and reserved in advance so
that the region is continuous. This space is [not yet used physically (in RAM or disk)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx).
Only the address range is reserved.

As the runtime currently does [not handle memory limits](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5049) it always attempts
to reserve [768MB](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/malloc.goc?name=go1.1.2#357) of virtual address space on 32 bit machines.

Even reserving memory has a cost, your OS (windows) has to allocate memory to hold the 
allocation information, a [Virtual Address Descriptor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/06/03/424905.aspx). 
If you haven't got enough memory to hold this descriptor the reservation will fail. 
On the other hand, it may just be that the virtual address space can't hold 768MB of 
continuous space and fails (for example due to fragmentation).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started cmd with admin privileges but it's same. It's not just only godoc when i try compile my code in eclipse JUNO it gives me same exception. i'm having a 8GB ram.

Comment: Excuse me but I haven't seen that you're running go 1.2rc5, have you tried using 1.1.2? There were some changes in the allocator.

Comment: Yes i tried 1.1.2 and it's still the same. While searching for the solutions I find that 32 bit development is not suitable for GO is it true?

Comment: So you have a 32 bit OS and 8GB RAM installed? Then you don't have 8GB RAM but 3.x GB of usable RAM which might explain why you're running into memory problems. Upgrade to a 64 bit OS to use your full 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I never used windows as a development station, so I'm just make assumptions here.

I assume whether your system doesn't have enough disposable ram to run godoc, or you run godoc in a restricted mode unable to ask for memory allocation to the kernel.

Anyway I think the critical part of the interesting part of the error message is "cannot reverve arena virtual address space" and it would worth asking your question on the golang-nuts mailing list.